# How to detect shortcuts from host OS on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to be able to switch from guest OS to host os using shortcuts.

For example the VirtualBox is running in the *workspace2* in fullscreen mode, and I have a binding to switch workspaces in Ubuntu (clicking <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>></kbd> ).

How do I make the guest OS to listen to them, so I can switch to *workspace1*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it switch if you hit the host key prior to <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>></kbd>?